# Python CustomTkinter CTKButton change of state not taking effect?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am writing an app with CustomTkinter. I have created a collapsible frame with a button to collapse and uncollapse the frame. But I need to be able to disable this button. I wrote a function `disable_uncollapse` to do this but the button remains clickable.

```
import tkinter

import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image
ctk.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
appWidth, appHeight = 600, 700
class CollapsibleFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    """
    Class to create a collapsible frame. Starts as collapsed. Row and Column are row and column of parent frame it should be gridded to
    """
    def __init__(self, master, row:int=0,column:int=0,collapsed_text:str='',**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.collapsed_text=collapsed_text
        # add widgets onto the frame, for example:
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self,
                                      text=self.collapsed_text)
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.row=row
        self.column=column
        self.collapsed_widgets=[]
        # load icons
        self.down_chevron=ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("chevron_up.png"), size=(7, 7))
        self.up_chevron = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open("chevron_down.png"), size=(7, 7))
        # Add hide/unhide buttons
        self.collapsebuton = ctk.CTkButton(self,
                                           image=self.down_chevron,text="")
        self.collapsebuton.grid(row=0, column=1,
                                padx=20, pady=20,
                                sticky="e")
        self.collapsebuton.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.collapse())

        self.uncollapsebuton = ctk.CTkButton(self,
                                           image=self.up_chevron,text="")
        self.uncollapsebuton.grid(row=0, column=1,
                                padx=20, pady=20,
                                sticky="e")
        self.uncollapsebuton.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.uncollapse())


    def hide(self):
        """ Completely hides frame """
        print('hiding')
        self.grid_forget()
    def unhide(self):
        """ Completely unhides frame """
        print('unhiding')
        self.grid(row=self.row,column=self.column,sticky='ew')
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        #self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    def collapse(self):
        """ Collapses frame, leaving icon to uncollapse """
        print('collapsing')
        # hide all known items
        sub_items=self.grid_slaves()
        for item in sub_items:
            self.collapsed_widgets.append(item) # save these items for if we want to un-hide them later
            item.grid_remove()
        # add back uncollapse button, title
        self.uncollapsebuton.grid()
        self.collapsebuton.grid_remove()
        self.title_label.grid()
    def uncollapse(self):
        """ Uncollapses frame, leaving icon to collapse """
        print('uncollapsing')
        # unhide previously hidden widgets
        for item in self.collapsed_widgets:
            item.grid()
        self.collapsed_widgets.clear()
        self.unhide()
        self.collapsebuton.grid()
        self.uncollapsebuton.grid_remove()
    def disable_uncollapse(self):
        self.uncollapsebuton.configure(state=ctk.DISABLED)
        self.collapsebuton.configure(state='disabled')

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("My awesome window")
        self.geometry(f"{appWidth}x{appHeight}")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        create_vault_frame = CollapsibleFrame(self,row=0,column=0,collapsed_text="Panel1")
        create_vault_frame.uncollapse()
        new_label=ctk.CTkLabel(create_vault_frame,text='aaah')
        new_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
        create_vault_frame.disable_uncollapse()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I have tried changing how I change the state including trying the following options:

```
self.uncollapsebuton.configure(state=ctk.DISABLED)
self.uncollapsebuton.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
self.uncollapsebuton.configure(state="DISABLED")
```

I have also tried running `self.update()` from within the frame.

But none of them seem to take effect. I have added a print statement to check, and this function is indeed getting called, the state is even changing, but the button remains clickable.

Comment: Setting a `CTkButton` to disabled state does not actually disable the widget.  It just set the text color, disable hover effect and does not call the callback assigned to `command` option.  So the callback on event binding is still working.  Why don't you use the `command` option instead of binding event?

Answer (score 0):

te dejo el codigo que funciona para mi     def insert_view(self, view):
index = self.views.index(view)
boton = self.botones[index]

```
    boton.configure(state="disabled")
    self.content_frame.destroy()
    self.content_frame = view(self, usuario=self.usuario, fg_color="#F4F4F4")
    self.content_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    if self.btn_anterior is not None and self.btn_anterior != boton:
        self.btn_anterior.configure(state="normal")

    self.btn_anterior = boton
```